# `memcpy` doesn't copy all bytes

Tags: c, memory, memcpy

I'm trying to copy bytes of a struct to a char* which act as a buffer. To do this I convert my struct(`vdnxfs_node`) to an array of char. This struct is 64 bytes long, while the buffer is 1024 bytes.
When doing `memcpy`, however, only the first 4 bytes of the struct are copied into the buffer.

File: `fs.c`

```c
int mkfs(uint8_t _dev, uint8_t _mode)
{
    // VDNXFS_BUFFER_SZ = 1024
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(VDNXFS_BUFFER_SZ);

    // Other code non relevant to the question...

    // vdnxfs_init_new_node(); returns an `vdnxfs_node*` initialized
    // as `calloc(1, sizeof(vdnxfs_node));`
    vdnxfs_node* node = vdnxfs_init_new_node();
    node->st_mode = VDNXFS_ST_IRWXU | VDNXFS_ST_IRGRP | VDNXFS_ST_IXGRP | VDNXFS_ST_IROTH | VDNXFS_ST_IXOTH;
    node->st_uid = 1;
    node->st_gid = 1;
    node->st_pid = 0;
    node->st_size = 0;
    node->st_slnk = 1;
    node->st_atime = 0xffff;
    node->st_mtime = 0xffff;
    node->st_ctime = 0xffff;
    strcpy(node->st_name, "ROOT_DIR\0");

    // With this I get the array of bytes(char) of the struct
    char* node_buf = encode_dnxfs_node(node);

    // Updating the buffer
    memcpy(buf, node_buf, sizeof(vdnxfs_node));

    // Here I write the content of `buf` to a file.
    if(!vdnxfs_write_disk(_dev, block, off, buf))
    {
        printf("Couldn't write superblock to disk `sda%d`.", _dev);
        return -1;
    }
    free(buf);
    free(node_buf);
}
```

File: `stat.h`

```c
typedef struct __vdnxfs_node
{
    uint16_t st_mode;
    uint16_t st_uid;
    uint16_t st_gid;
    uint32_t st_pid; // Parent ID
    uint32_t st_size;
    uint8_t st_slnk; // Number of symbolic links
    time_t st_atime;
    time_t st_mtime;
    time_t st_ctime;
    char st_name[16];
}vdnxfs_node;
```

File: `stat.c`
Brief: Convert all bytes of a node to an array of chars

```c
char* encode_dnxfs_node(vdnxfs_node* node)
{
    if(!node) // Node is null
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(vdnxfs_node));

    if(!buffer)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate buffer for encoding.");
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(buffer, node, sizeof(vdnxfs_node));

    return buffer;
}
```

File: `disk.c`
Brief: Write the content of `_buf` on a file. The content wrote on disk is always `1024 bytes` long as defined in `VDNXFS_BUFFER_SZ`. `_off` is the offset inside the block.

```c
char* vdnxfs_write_disk(uint8_t _dev, size_t _block, size_t _off, char* _buf)
{
    char* fl_name = (char*)calloc(1, 7);
    strcpy(fl_name, vdnxfs_disks[_dev]->fl_name);

    FILE* fp_buf = fopen(fl_name, "r+b");

    if(!fp_buf)
    {
        printf("DISK DRIVER: Couldn't open Disk %s\n", fl_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    // If succesful
    if(!fseek(fp_buf, (_block * VDNXFS_BUFFER_SZ) + _off, SEEK_SET))
    {
        fputs(_buf, fp_buf);
    }else { return NULL; }

    fclose(fp_buf);

    return _buf;
}
```

`sizeof(vdnxfs_node)` returns `64`, meaning that is not padded.
I really think that the problem is not in the actual `memcpy` but in my `vdnxfs_write_disk(...)` function, even though I already tested by writing both null char and random characters, and it worked as expected. In my test I wrote 1024 `a` characters onto the file, and it worked.
So, either there's a problem of mine when I try to `memcpy` `node_buf` into `buf` or I am missing something.

Note: If I print `node_buf` char by char I get this result:

```
φ                                           ROOT_DIR
```

However, when analyzing the file with an hex-editor, the first 4 bytes of the block are:

`ED 01 01 00`

The rest are all `00`

It's all store in little-endian mode. `01ED` is indeed `node->st_mode`. I'm sure it is right because I'm using linux permissions, and `755` is `1ED` in hex.

Comment: `VDNXFS_BUFFER_SZ` is probably different than the size of `vdnxfs_node`.

Comment: Study the art of creating a [mre]. I'm pretty sure you can figure out if it has anything to do with writing to the disk or not.

Comment: Yes, it does.  It is unbelievably unlikely that your library has a buggy memcpy().

Comment: Unrelated, prolly wanna fix the blatant memory leak in `mkfs`. The dynamic buffer return from `char* node_buf = encode_dnxfs_node(node);` is never freed, and the pointer never retained... anywhere. Along the same line, `node` looks like it is leaked as well (same function).

Comment: Slightly unrelated question, but why memcpy the bytes at all into a temporary array?    Why not pass `(char*)node` directly to `vdnxfs_write_disk` ?

Comment: @JL2210 yes, `VDNXFS_BUFFER_SZ` is `1024 bytes` while `vdnxfs_node` is `64 bytes`, but it's irrelevant. When I `memcpy` I just need to copy those `64 bytes` of the struct onto the first `64 bytes` of the buffer.

Comment: Fyi, `fputs(_buf, fp_buf);` will stop dumping data upon reaching what it thinks is a terminating null (i.e. the first zero-value octet starting at the address `_buf`). I.e. that's the wrong function to be using for your write if the data can have *any* embedded zero-octet.  Is there some reason you're *not* using `fwrite` and a proper determinate size value?

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually I didn't write it, but at the end of the function I do `free(node_buf);` and `free(buf);`. I'll update the code.

Comment: You don't need the `\0` at the end of your string. C strings are already null-terminated. Also, never cast the result of `malloc`, and never use the size of a type in either `memcpy` or `malloc`, use the size of a variable instead (e.g. `memcpy(d, s, sizeof(d_type))` is bad, use `memcpy(d, s, sizeof(*d))`).

Comment: I followed what @selbie told, directly passing `(char*)node` into `vdnxfs_write_disk`. However, when I do that, as well as passing the size of `node`(which is `sizeof(vdnxfs_node)`, `64 bytes`), `fwrite` will write over the size I specified and thus writing 'random' stuffs. Also something that I noticed is that even if I `fseek` every time to the location I want to write, my actual data is written a few bytes over. I really checked every line of my code, used `free` for every allocated variable but still I think I'm getting memory leaks somewhere.

Comment: @Diego - The only reason why fwrite would copy more than the number of bytes you specified is because you opened the file as "text" instead of "binary". I see in your code you specified `r+b`, which should work...

Comment: @selbie Thank you for the help, and actually thanks everyone for hints about my code. I actually found the problem and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I noticed that I was passing to `vdnxfs_write_disk` the wrong buffer size(I was passing `VDXNFS_BUFFER_SZ` instead of the size of the data I wanted to write). I was also passing to `vdnxfs_write_disk` the wrong offset and block.
I was actually passing `1` for the block arguments and as `fseek`'s offset is calculated as `(block * VDNXFS_BUFFER_SZ) + off` the offset of `fseek` was going over `1024 bytes` which was wrong.

If someone is interested, here is my final (fixed) result of `mkfs`:

```c
int mkfs(uint8_t _dev, uint8_t _mode)
{
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    char* signature_buf = vdnxfs_read_disk(_dev, 0, 4, 4);
    memcpy(buf, signature_buf, sizeof(size_t));
    free(signature_buf);

    // Signing the disk with the appopriate signature.
    size_t signature = _mode == vdnxfs_system ? VDNXFS_BDSK_SIGNATURE : VDNXFS_DDSK_SIGNATURE;
    // printf("Signature: %X\n", signature);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // Disk signature starts at 4th byte
        buf[i] = ((signature >> (8 * i)) & 0xff);
    }

    // Updating the content to disk
    if(!vdnxfs_write_disk(_dev, 0, 4, buf, 4))
    {
        printf("Couldn't sign disk `sda%d`.", _dev);
        return -1;
    }

    // Getting the Super Block based on the mode.
    // Boot/System FS stores the superblock from bytes 1024 to 2047
    // Data FS stores the superblock from bytes 512 to 1535
    size_t block = 0;
    size_t off = _mode == vdnxfs_system ? VDNXFS_BFS_SBLK_START : VDNXFS_DFS_SBLK_START;

    vdnxfs_node* node = (vdnxfs_node*)calloc(1, 64);
    node->st_mode = VDNXFS_ST_IRWXU | VDNXFS_ST_IRGRP | VDNXFS_ST_IXGRP | VDNXFS_ST_IROTH | VDNXFS_ST_IXOTH;
    node->st_uid = 1;
    node->st_gid = 1;
    node->st_pid = 0;
    node->st_size = 0;
    node->st_slnk = 1;
    node->st_atime = 0xffff;
    node->st_mtime = 0xffff;
    node->st_ctime = 0xffff;
    strcpy(node->st_name, "ROOT_DIR");
    // Updating the superblock to disk
    if(!vdnxfs_write_disk(_dev, block, off, encode_dnxfs_node(node), 64))
    {
        printf("Couldn't write superblock to disk `sda%d`.", _dev);
        free(node);
        free(buf);
        return -1;
    }

    free(node);
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: I would add a compile time assert that `sizeof(vdnxfs_node) == 64`.  Easy trick in C: `int assert_test[sizeof(vdnxfs_node) == 64 ? 1: -1];`  Because the day you change the compiler (or someone tweaks a header file) that could add new padding into the node struct, your code would be seriously broken.